# Error al compilar gulp

Tags: gulp

Tengo un archivo gulp que al momento de usar concat me manda un error al localizar la ruta de un archivo.

El error es el siguiente

Error: Error: File not found with singular glob: /Users/mac/Documents/Proyectos/Gulp/build/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

mi archivo gulp es el siguiente:

```
"use strict";

  const gulp         = require("gulp"),
        browserSync  = require("browser-sync").create(),
        autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
        babel        = require("gulp-babel"),
        cleanCSS     = require("gulp-clean-css"),
        htmlmin      = require("gulp-htmlmin"),
        imagemin     = require("gulp-imagemin"),
        plumber      = require("gulp-plumber"),
        pngquant     = require("imagemin-pngquant"),
        gulpif       = require("gulp-if"),
        uncss        = require("gulp-uncss"),
        useref       = require("gulp-useref"),
        concat       = require("gulp-concat"),
        webp         = require("gulp-webp"),
        pug          = require("gulp-pug"),
        uglify       = require("gulp-uglify"),
        browserify   = require("gulp-browserify"),
        sass         = require("gulp-sass"),
        dir          = {
          src : "src",
          development : "build/development",
          production : "build/production",
          nm : "node_modules",
        },
        files        = {
          CSS : [
            `${dir.nm}/animate.css/source/animate.min.css`,
            "css/main.css",
          ],
          mCSS : "main.min.css",
          JS : [
            `${dir.nm}/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`,
            "js/main.js",
          ],
          mJS : "main.min.js",
        },
        opts = {
          pug                 : {
            pretty            : true,
            locals            : {
              files           : files
            }
          },
          es6                 : { presets : ['es2015'] },
          sass                : { outputStyle : "compressed" },
          imagemin            : {
            progressive       : true,
            use               : [pngquant()]
          },
          svgmin              : {
            plugin            : [
              { convertColors : false },
              { removeAttrs   : { attrs : ["fill"] } }
            ]
          },
          uncss               : { html : [`${dir.development}/*.html`] },
          autoprefixer        : {
            browsers          : ["last 5 versions"],
            cascade           : false
          },
          htmlmin : {collapseWhitespace: true}
        };

// Task pug
gulp.task("pug", function(){
  return gulp.src("src/templates/**/*.pug")
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(pug(opts.pug))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dir.development}`))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream : true }));
});

// Task JS
gulp.task("js", function() {
  return gulp.src("src/js/**.*js")
    .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe( babel(opts.es6) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.development}/js`) )
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream : true}));
});

// Task SASS
gulp.task("sass", function(){
  return gulp.src("src/sass/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe( sass(opts.sass) )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dir.development}/css`))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream : true}));
});

// Task img
gulp.task('img', () => {
  return gulp.src( `${dir.src}/img/**/*.+(png|jpge|jpg|gif)` )
    .pipe( plumber() )
    .pipe( imagemin(opts.imagemin))
    .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.development}/img`) );
});

// Task imgprod
gulp.task('imgProduction', () => {
  return gulp.src( `${dir.development}/img/**/*.+(png|jpge|jpg|gif)` )
    .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.production}/img`) );
});

//task webp
gulp.task('webp', () => {
    return gulp.src( `${dir.src}/img/**/*.+(png|jpeg|jpg)` )
    .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe( webp() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.development}/img/webp`) );
});

//task webpProd
gulp.task('webpProduction', () => {
    return gulp.src( `${dir.development}/img/webp)` )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.production}/img/webp`) );
});

//task svg
gulp.task("svg", () => {
  return gulp.src(`${dir.src}/img/svg/*.svg`)
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe( svgming(opts.svgmin) )
  .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.development}/img/svg`));
});

//task svgProdu
gulp.task("svgProduction", () => {
  return gulp.src(`${dir.development}/img/svg/*.svg`)
  .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.production}/img/svg`));
});

// ************AQUI ES DONDE ME MARCA EL ERROR <********************
gulp.task('css', () => {
    return gulp.src(files.CSS)
        .pipe( concat(files.mCSS) )
        .pipe( uncss(opts.uncss) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer(opts.autoprefixer) )
        .pipe( cleanCSS() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.dist}/css`) );
});

//task js
gulp.task("js", () => {
  return gulp.src(files.JS)
  .pipe( concat(files.mJS) )
  .pipe( uglify() )
  .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.production}/js`) );
});

//task html
gulp.task("html", () => {
  return gulp.src(`${dir.development}/*.html`)
  .pipe( useref() )
  .pipe( htmlmin(opts.htmlmin) )
  .pipe( gulp.dest(`${dir.development}`));
});

// task watch
gulp.task("watch", () => {
  gulp.watch("src/templates/**/*.pug", ["pug"]);
  gulp.watch("src/js/**/*.js", ["js"]);
  gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.scss", ["sass"]);
});

// task server
gulp.task("server", () => {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: `${dir.development}`,
      routes: {
        "/node_modules": `${dir.nm}`,
        }
      }
  })
});


// Tareas que se ejecutan
gulp.task("default", ["pug", "js", "sass", "watch", "server"]);
gulp.task("images", ["img", "webp", "svg"]);
gulp.task("production", ["css", "js", "html", "imgProduction", "webpProduction"]);
```

La vista es la siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="es")
head
  meta(charset="UTF-8")
  meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0")
  title Rianjani
  // build:css css/estilos.min.css
  each css in files.CSS
    link(rel="stylesheet", href=`${css}`)
  // endbuild
body
  h1 Hola Mundo
  p error resuelto

  // build:js js/main.min.js
  each js in files.JS
    script(src=`${js}`)
  // endbuild
```

Y la estructura de carpetas es la siguiente:

```
-build 
-- development 
--- img
--- sass 
--- js
--- index.html
-- production 
-node_modules
-src
-- img
-- sass 
-- js
-- templates
```

**Cuando compilo la tarea produccion para mandar todo a la carpeta de produccion es cuando me marca el error**

Comment: Se puede ver que has definido la tarea `js` dos veces. Seguramente este es el motivo por el que no encuentra el archivo `js` ya que la primera definicion nunca se ejecuta.

Comment: esa tarea si funciona, el probelma no es ese, el error me lo marca al querer juntar los archivos en uno solo, cuando corre la tarea html

Comment: Es decir que si ejecutas `$ gulp html`, obtienes error, pero si ejecutas `$ gulp js`, no. Es eso lo que nos estas diciendo?

Comment: correcto, el error que marca (puesto al principio del articulo) marca que la ruta de los archivos js no es la correcta y no puede hacer el archivo mimificado. No se si me doy a entender

Comment: Y el archivo `build/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` esta en ese directorio? Porque según la estructura de carpetas, la ruta debería ser `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` (ya que *build* y *node_modules*, estarían al mismo nivel)

Comment: no, no esta en el mismo, esta dos directorios arribas, pero cuando ejecuto la tarea default con esas rutas toma los archivos, solo cuando quiero que los mande a la carpeta de production pone la ruta mal.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)? Se me ocurre que podrías modificar el `path` a `nm`, así: `nm : __dirname + "node_modules"` y así el `path` será absoluto y no relativo.